# jersey client in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, client, jersey

I have a Jersey webservice which has its client in C#. Following the the snippet.

```
var request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] b = memstreamxml.ToArray();
        stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        stream.Close();
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

With this request that post with xml bytes, I am getting either 400 or 415 error response. I have tried to @Consumes various MediaTypes, none working currently. Could someone give me insight how to send xml request from C# to jersey web service? I am also using @XmlRootElement to with my pojo to deal with input xml.

Thank for help in advance.

Comment: I got it working when the request contentType is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and jersey webservice @Consumes APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED. It seems like there is no way to directly Marshall the XML into pojo object.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working when the request contentType is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and jersey webservice @Consumes APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED. Infact it wasn't problem with contentType but inability to Marshall xml input into POJO objects as expected by webresource. So, as soon as I modify the service's parameter type as String, it start working. Of course you need to parse string xml to build an object unless there is other way.